# Chain elongation with a substituent

Tags: organic-chemistry, grignard-reagent

Can this compound exist in a stable form. If so, can it be used to add the chloroethyl group to a carbonyl compound

[image: this is the compound I’m asking about]

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a stable species. It will immediately eliminate to give ethene.

If you want to add a C2 unit you're better off with the commercially available vinyl Grignard.